# How to define the use of utf-8 in Doctrine 2 in Zend Framework application.ini, when using Bisna

Tags: zend-framework, character-encoding, doctrine, doctrine-orm

The following [ZendCasts cast](http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-doctrine-2-entities), shows a way to use doctrine 2 in a zend framework environment.
Using this configuration, how can I make the connection use a utf-8 charset so the magic of `"SET NAMES 'utf8'"` will happen ?

What I'm really searching for is a way to configure it using the application.ini file.
If that's not possible using this configuration, how can this be done by code ? an `_initDoctrine` method in the Bootstratp file ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**
It appears there's a post connect event which handles this, but I don't see how can I set it up via application.ini (if possible at all).
If not, can I set it up via a bootstrap method ? Will the bootstrap method run before any other doctrine connection code run, when relying on the Bisna library ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

works fine for me

```
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.driverOptions.1002 = "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
```

`1002` is the integer value of [`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo.constants.mysql-attr-init-command):

> Command to execute when connecting to the MySQL server. Will
>   automatically be re-executed when reconnecting.
>   Note, this constant can only be used in the driver_options array when constructing a new
>   database handle.

Answer (score 92):

If you are not using Bisna, you could simply do something like the following:

Pass the config stuff directly to EntityManager's connection options
(although `driverOptions` is not documented)

```
// $options is a simple array to hold your data
$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver'   => $options['conn']['driv'],
    'user'     => $options['conn']['user'],
    'password' => $options['conn']['pass'],
    'dbname'   => $options['conn']['dbname'],
    'host'     => $options['conn']['host'],
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'driverOptions' => array(
        1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8'
    )
);

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
```

I'm using the following custom bootstrap resource to initialize doctrine therefore `$options` is in application.ini and is accessible there by `$this->getOptions()`;

```
// \library\My\Application\Resource\Doctrine.php
class My_Application_Resource_Doctrine extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract
 {

    public function init()
    {
       $options = $this->getOptions();
       $config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
       //doctrine autoloader, config and other initializations
       ...
       $connectionOptions = array(
               .... //see above
       );
       $em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
       $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
       $registry->em = $em;
       return $em;
    }
}
```

It will bootstrap automatically if you put in application.ini

```
resources.doctrine.conn.host = '127.0.0.1'
resources.doctrine.conn.user = '...'
resources.doctrine.conn.pass = '...'
....
```

Comment: You are The Man! Thanx! Solution for "How to set Doctrine2 to connect to MySql using UTF-8 charset".

Answer (score 12):

this worked for me. `config/autoload/doctrine.local.php`

```
<?php
return array(
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
            'orm_default' => array(
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => array(
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '3306',
                    'user' => '...',
                    'password' => '...',
                    'dbname' => '...',

                    'driverOptions' => array(
                        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
                    )

                ),

            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thank you. I suggest to change the line `1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8'` into `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'`

Comment: Thank you. Works in Zend Expressive 3 as well.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to add it via application.ini, provided you use ZendX_Doctrine2 (at https://github.com/mridgway/ZendX_Doctrine2) with MySQL.

Then here's the line you need in application.ini:

```
resources.entitymanagerfactory.connectionOptions.driverOptions.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8"
```

(1002 == PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND)

Don't forget to correctly set

```
default-character-set=utf8
```

in your my.cnf

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for Doctrine 2, and ZendCasts is using Bisna, I *believe* you can just add this to your configuration.ini file

```
resources.doctrine.dbal.connections.default.parameters.driverOptions.charset = "utf8"
```

I'm not exactly sure how to test if it is sticking or not but let us know.

Comment: You are correct regarding the use of Bisna, and the line you gave does have it's affect. However - according to http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/dbal/2.0/en/reference/events.html, there's a post connect event to which I need to subscribe a MysqlSessionInit object with the utf-8 charset. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the default table charset like that to utf8:

```
// Create new Doctrine Manager instance
$doctrineManager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();

// Set charset to UTF8
$doctrineManager->setAttribute(
    Doctrine_Core::ATTR_DEFAULT_TABLE_CHARSET,
    'utf8'
);
```

*Quote:*

> an _initDoctrine method in the Bootstratp file ?

Yes.

Answer (score 0):

For LoSo library and Doctrine 2 and MySQL add

```
resources.doctrine2.connection.driverOptions.1002 = "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
```

to your application.ini

Answer (score -1):

I have this in my bootstrap:

```
    protected function _initDoctrineLibrary()
{
    require_once('Doctrine/Doctrine.php');
    $this->getApplication()->getAutoloader()->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'),'Doctrine');

    $manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
    $manager->setAttribute(
        Doctrine::ATTR_MODEL_LOADING,
        Doctrine::MODEL_LOADING_CONSERVATIVE
    );
    $config = $this->getOption('doctrine');
    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($config['dsn'],'doctrine');
    $conn->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_USE_NATIVE_ENUM, true);
    return $conn;
}
```

where in the application.ini you see

```
doctrine.dsn = "mysql://user:password@host/databasename"
```

I think you can do something similar