# Doctrine 2: How/why do certain characters get translated (i.e. ® becomes Â®)

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

If I have a text field with an "®" in it and I persist it, why does it translate into "Â®" when I look at the data in the db?

Comment: Ensure you view your database with the same character set as the data in your webapp.

Comment: Found the answer in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391045/how-to-define-the-use-of-utf-8-in-doctrine-2-in-zend-framework-application-ini