# Character encoding in form

Tags: html, linux, encoding, utf-8

I have a php/html application over a MySql database. Database encoding is UTF-8 and so are HTML files (`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` and `<meta charset="utf-8">`).

The thing is, there is inconsistency, as in a list page (plain html, no forms), I can see UTF-8 characters properly ([image]), and also when I select values in mysql admin, but in the edit form I see wrong characters ([image]) inside input text fields. **This happens when I update a value inside mysql admin**.

And the inverse occurs, **if I update a value through the form** I see characters properly inside input text field, but wrong in list (html, no forms) ([image]).

As I read the problem may be in the files encoding, which is confusing, as, if I list with `file -i` (I use linux) I see a mixture of utf-8 and us-ascii files, but if I open then with sublime text 3, I can see UTF-8 on all of them, and even if i `save with encoding utf-8`, `file -i` doesn't change result.

I also read that `file -i` is more a guess than a real result, so I'm quite puzzled in which encoding files have, how can I change them for real. There are many files involved, templates, libraries, etc.

**EDIT:**
To connect to database, I use Doctrine (which I ignore internal mechanisms) and also `@mysql_connect`, which I force with `$this->charset_utf8 = true`

**SOLUTION**

Not really a duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through), but @deceze is right, I needed to configure Doctrine connection as explained in this [SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6035859):

```
$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver'   => $options['conn']['driv'],
    'user'     => $options['conn']['user'],
    'password' => $options['conn']['pass'],
    'dbname'   => $options['conn']['dbname'],
    'host'     => $options['conn']['host'],
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'driverOptions' => array(
    1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8'
    )
);

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
```

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you're forgetting to set the database connection encoding somewhere.

Comment: @deceze I use Doctrine (which I ignore internal mechanisms) and also `@mysql_connect`, which I force with `$this->charset_utf8 = true`. About your *duplicated* flag, there are MANY similar questions, but not with this same problem, only in input text files. I'll read your link carefully to see if I missed something. Other solutions didn't help me

Comment: You might also want to see [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/). FWIW, I have no idea how `$this->charset_utf8 = true` is supposed to relate to `mysql_connect`, but I'm pretty certain that's about where your problem is.

Comment: It was a Doctrine config. issue, thanks